# Can I remap ctrl-j and ctrl-k in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimrc

I would like to remap <kbd>ctrl + j</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl + d</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl + k</kbd> to  <kbd>ctrl + u</kbd> for moving half a page down and up in normal mode. I have tried with

```
noremap <c-j> <c-d>
noremap <c-k> <c-u>
```

in my `.vimrc`, but the key function does not change.

I [read on the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)) that

> The Ctrl-J character represents the linefeed and is internally used by Vim to represent the Nul character. You cannot create a map for Ctrl-J by using the following command:
>
> "The following command doesn't work
>
> :imap  Newlinecharacter

Is there any way to remap <kbd>ctrl + j</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl + k</kbd> in vim?

Comment: Is is possible to see why this question was downvoted, so I know if I should change the format of my questions in the future?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible, and your commands are right. Are you sure your .vimrc is loaded? Check output of `:map` and `:scriptnames`.

Comment: I discovered that I had an interfering addon, this works after disabling that addon. Weirdly, I previously tested this with an empty `.vimrc` (apart from these lines), but that was not working, just disabling the addon and keeping the rest of my current config...

Answer (score 8):

With those, you first need to unmap them:

For example, for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> put the following line in the file '.vimrc':

```
let g:BASH_Ctrl_j = 'off'
```

Comment: Thanks! Through you answer I found this thread that talks about the same solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092982/mapping-c-j-to-something-in-vim, so this seems to be the way to go. For some reason, it is still not working for me, even after clearing everything else from my `.vimrc`. Instead, I just ended up using capital `J` and `K` in the end.

Comment: This does not work for me. Pressing `<C-j>` in insert mode still produces a new line.

Comment: Maybe You're doing it on wrong account?

Answer (score 3):

Almost there. You need to add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-j> <C-d>
nnoremap <C-k> <C-u>
```

When I want to know how vim works I find useful `:help <command>`.

Comment: This is what I tried. Sorry if it wasn't clear, I edited the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did some tests and this is working for me. Note that `noremap` and `nnoremap` are not the same thing. If you want a non-recursive normal mode mapping `nnoremap` is what you are looking for.

Comment: My apologies, I did not notice the extra "n" at the start of each line. I also discovered that I had an interfering addon, this works after disabling that addon and so does mu original solution. Weirdly, I previously tested this with an empty `.vimrc` (apart from these lines), but that was not working, just disabling the addon and keeping the rest of my current config...