# remap vim CTRL-a to CTRL-i

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to adjust vim to count in visual block mode. See [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/visual-block-mode-edit-with-sequential-number) post for more info:
I use Ctrl+a for my tmux binding (replaces Ctrl+b), and that is not going to change.

I tried everything [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329641/can-i-remap-ctrl-j-and-ctrl-k-in-vim). Nothing seems to work.
I think vim is taking my key combo, and still trying to run Ctrl+a. I need to completely make vim start using a different key combination for the same thing that Ctrl+a did.

nnoremap, noremap, vmap. Every time I try {visual block mode} + `g` + {new binding}. Nothing happens.

I tested outside of tmux btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the terminal, and not a GUI version of Vim, using Ctrl-I is going to be practically impossible.  That's because Ctrl-I is Tab and the terminal cannot distinguish between those two key sequences.  So when you're typing Ctrl-I, Vim is interpreting it as Tab and you're seeing unexpected behavior.

This isn't the case for most GUI environments, which can map keys independently.  So this *would* work in gvim.

You're probably going to need to pick a different key sequence.  Note that in a terminal, Ctrl-X, where X is a letter, is mapped to the ASCII sequence for that position in the alphabet.  Ctrl-I is ASCII 9 (the ninth letter of the alphabet), which is Tab.  So, you'll probably want to pick something that isn't assigned another meaning, and so avoid things like Ctrl-J and Ctrl-M.

Comment: Right, but mapping Ctrl-A to Ctrl-I is the same as mapping Ctrl-A to Tab, which already has a well-defined binding.